# Dropdown For next 10 years

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

what is the best way make a dropdown list in MVC4 (View) that show current year plus next 10 years? Should I make an enum and then include it in my view model and make a variable of that enum type?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Perhaps a for loop starting at DateTime.Now.Year and incrementing 9 times. How do you feel about Razor syntax?

Comment: Your enum solution would require a redeploy of your app every Dec. 31.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10)
```

will give you numbers that you can then use in the SelectList() constructor for your DropDownList

Answer (score 9):

When you use Enum for that it will hard coded .Every end of year you should have to re deploy the solution.So better to use as following code in your business layer and push into view layer then based on server Date every user can retrive the next 10 years.

```
 IList<int> years= Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

For razor you may use the following code

```
@Html.DropDownList("Year", Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10).ToList(), "-- Select Year --")
```

Answer (score 1):

add "new SelectList":

@Html.DropDownList("Year", new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10).ToList()), "-- Select Year --")

Comment: Please pay at least *basic* attention to formatting your answer. Otherwise you risk downvotes.

Comment: Plus it makes hardly any sense posting a new answer to a two-year old question with an *accepted* answer.